# NSManagedObject subclass with additional properties not defined in model

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is it possible to define additional properties to a NSManagedObject subclass that are not defined within the Core Data Model? I have a series of additional properties that I do not want to include in the model.

I am able to save the NSManagedObject to the context just fine, but when I close the app then run a fetch after starting the app again, the NSManagedObject contains all null values...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save those values you have to put them into your model, otherwise you are fine to create them each time the value is accessed and wasn't created earlier.

Lazy loading style.

```
- (NSString *)name {
    if (!name) {
        name = ...
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: These are properties that I do not want to save. I am not defining the getters because I have them defined as properties. If creating these additional properties is ok, any idea why a fetch returns null values for all properties (including the ones defined in the model)? The number of objects returned from the fetch is correct...

Comment: such properties are definitely not the reason. Most likely you've set the attributes to nil yourself. Double check this, with some `if`s or `NSAssert`s around the code where you set the values. Don't forget to save the context. And check all return values when available. Especially for the save. Could be that you insert the objects, save the empty objects, set some values and the next save fails.

Comment: I just did a fetch test using a generic NSManagedObject instead of my defined NSManaged object subclass and all values seem to be fine... Are you sure my class definition has nothing to with this?

Comment: Have you by any chance replaced the `@dynamic` accessors of your core data attributes with `@synthesize`?